# Using Python to load template excel file, insert a DataFrame to specific lines and save as a new file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsx, openpyxl

I'm having troubles writing something that I believe should be relatively easy.

I have a template excel file, that has some visualizations on it with a few spreadsheets. I want to write a scripts that loads the template, inserts an existing dataframe rows to specific cells on each sheet, and saves the new excel file as a new file.
The template already have all the cells designed and the visualization, so i will want to insert this data only without changing the design.

I tried several packages and none of them seemed to work for me.

Thanks for your help! :-)

Comment: When you say, "none of them seemed to work," can you clarify? Which packages did you try? Can you share some (or all) of your code? What didn't work?

Answer (score 2):

I have written a package for inserting Pandas DataFrames to Excel sheets (specific rows/cells/columns), it's called `pyxcelframe`:

https://pypi.org/project/pyxcelframe/

It has very simple and short documentation, and the method you need is `insert_frame`

So, let's say we have a Pandas DataFrame called `df` which we have to insert in the Excel file ("MyWorkbook") sheet named "MySheet" from the cell B5, we can just use `insert_frame` function as follows:

```
from pyxcelframe import insert_frame
from openpyxl import load_workbook

workbook = load_workbook("MyWorkbook.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook["MySheet"]

insert_frame(worksheet=worksheet,
             dataframe=df,
             row_range=(5, 0),
             col_range=(2, 0))
```

0 as the value of the second element of `row_range` or `col_range` means that there is no ending row or column specified, if you need specific ending row/column you can replace 0 with it.

Comment: Please, provide a code sample.

Comment: @JafarIsbarov I edited the answer and now it has a simple code sample.

Comment: @LUKASANUKVARI I believe you have the wrong link to your project. Shouldn't it be https://pypi.org/project/pyxcelframe/

Comment: @TylerHoussian You are right, thanks for that, I have changed the name of the package some time ago and forgot about this answer...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for xlwings. You didn't post any test data, but modyfing below to suit your needs should be quite straight-forward.

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book('your_excel_template.xlsx')
wb.sheets['Sheet1'].range('A1').value = df[your_selected_rows]
wb.save('new_file.xlsx')
wb.close()
```